# App without remote database

Tags: .net, database, embedded-database

If I want to create .NET app that needs database functionalities, but I do not want to use remote database, what should I use instead?

For example, 
1) web app which needs to store data in some kind of database
2) desktop app which need to store data in some kind of database

Comment: we generally call this embedded database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639846/what-is-a-good-embedded-database-to-use-with-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQL CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: SqlCE 3.5 won't work so well for a Web App (Ex1). There is a new version in the works that should work with ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a big list of embedded databases for .NET on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database). Personally I'd go for SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Here is an ADO.Net provider with EF support: [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)